# Is this a bug in Clang's C++20 concepts implementation? Unnecessary checking of constraints causes infinite template recursion

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, c++20, c++-concepts

I have this definition of a C++20 concept:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template <typename T> concept Numeric =
requires(T a, T b) {
    { a + b } -> std::same_as<T>;
    { a - b } -> std::same_as<T>;
    { a * b } -> std::same_as<T>;
    { a / b } -> std::same_as<T>;
};
```

I have this class template which uses the concept to constrain types it can be instantiated with:

*(most methods except the penultimate three have stub implementations for a minimal example)*

```cpp
template <Numeric T>
class Deferred {
public:
    Deferred(const Deferred& other) {}
    Deferred(T value) {}
    Deferred& operator+=(const Deferred& rhs) {
        return *this;
    }
    Deferred& operator/=(const Deferred& rhs) {
        return *this;
    }
    operator T() {
        return {};
    }

    friend Deferred operator/(Deferred lhs, const Deferred& rhs) {
        lhs /= rhs;
        return lhs;
    }

    // These last two methods are the ones causing the error
    friend Deferred operator+(Deferred lhs, const Deferred& rhs) {
        lhs += rhs;
        return lhs;
    }
    template <Numeric TO>
    operator TO() {
        return {};
    }
};
```

Finally, I have this short program using the `Deferred` clas:

```cpp
int main() {
    Deferred<double> result = Deferred<double>(100.0) / Deferred<double>(2.0);
}
```

This code compiles fine on recent versions of both GCC 11.2 [(demo)](https://godbolt.org/z/sa44axo7P) and MSVC 19.29 [(demo)](https://godbolt.org/z/rWhcnv9aq).

However on Clang 12.0.1, I get a compiler error that appears to be caused by infinite template recursion triggered when checking if a type satisfies the `Numeric` constraint [(demo)](https://godbolt.org/z/v96aqf1xY).

Upon further inspection, it appears that Clang is being prompted to check if the type `Deferred<double>` satisfies the `Numeric` constraint, this being triggered by the division in `main()` which in turn triggers an instantiation of `Deferred<double>::operator Deferred<Deferred<double>>` for reasons that are unclear to me.

If the last two functions within `Deferred` are removed, the code compiles fine on all tested compilers.

*Interestingly*, if the constraints within `Numeric` are reordered such that no operator which is overloaded for `Deferred` appears as the first constraint (i.e. starting with neither `+` nor `/`), the error is also not triggered. I expect this is due to short-circuiting preventing evaluation of further constraints at the first failure.

Finally, if the template for `operator TO()` is changed to `template <typename TO>`, the error is not triggered.

**Is Clang being overly preëmptive in checking concepts constraints here, or is its behaviour correct and the other compilers are missing something?**

> I can't see any reason why it would try to call the generic cast operator for `Deferred`, unless mixing const and non-const versions of `Deferred` might trigger it in the division operator, or if there is some other implicit conversion here that I am missing.

### Update

Changing the cast operator to `explicit operator TO()` stops the compiler error on Clang, so it looks like implicit conversions are the cause of the error, but I am still unsure why this is the case.

**Why is an implicit conversion needed in a division expression where all variables are of the same type?**

Comment: Not an answer, but that `template <Numeric TO> operator TO();` method, which is at the heart of the issue here, is certainly firing off alarm bells in my mind. I would expect it to cause more headaches in the future. Allowing implicit conversion to any and all Numeric feels dangerous. At the very least, I would make it explicit.

Comment: The intended behaviour is to allow converting to anything numeric, but I think I now see that the problem is not in allowing conversion to anything numeric, but allowing so _implicitly_. It looks like the benefits here might be outweighed by the disadvantages. The discrepancy between compilers is still interesting, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a clang bug. Here's a reduced example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept Numeric =
    requires(T a) {
        foo(a);
    };

struct Deferred {
    friend void foo(Deferred);
    template <Numeric TO> operator TO();
};

static_assert(Numeric<Deferred>);
```

When checking to see if `foo(a)` is a valid expression for a `Deferred`, we have to do name lookup, find a function, and see if we can convert all the parameters. In this case, this involves copy-initializing a `Deferred` from an lvalue of type `Deferred`. This should *only* consider constructors because we're in this case [[dcl.init.general]/15.6.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-15.6.2):

> - Otherwise, if the initialization is direct-initialization, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated ([over.match.ctor]), and the best one is chosen through overload resolution ([over.match]). Then: [...]

We only consider conversion functions in the subsequent bullet:

> - Otherwise (i.e., for the remaining copy-initialization cases), user-defined conversions that can convert from the source type to the destination type or (when a conversion function is used) to a derived class thereof are enumerated as described in [over.match.copy], and the best one is chosen through overload resolution ([over.match]). [...]

Which makes sense - that's what constructors are for, conversion functions are to get to a *different* type (not the same one).

But clang here is trying to do `a.operator Deferred()` anyway (which is obviously infinitely recursive) and that's not correct. Filed [51549](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51549).